For any extension $\tau: A\to Q\left(B\right)$, how to find a trivial extension $\tau_0:A\to Q\left(B\right)$ s.t. $\tau\oplus \tau_0$ is essential?
First, we give some definitions.
Definition: Let $A, B$ be two $C^*$-algebras, an extension of $A$ by $B$ is a short exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
0\to B\to E\to A\to 0
\end{equation*}
of $C^*$-algebras.
Definition: Suppose $B$ is an ideal(closed two side) of $E$. We say $B $ is essential if
\begin{equation*}
\{x\in E: xb=bx=0\text{ for all $b\in B$}\}=\{0\}.
\end{equation*}
Moreover, we say the extension is essential. By the property of Multiplier algebra, we have the homomorphism $\sigma : E\to M\left(B\right)$, which could induces an homomorphism $\tau: A=E/B\to M\left(B\right)/B$. Using the technique about algebra extension, we know the map $\tau: A\to M\left(B\right)/B$ also induces an extension of $A$ by $B$.
Definition: Let $A$ and $B$ be two $C^*$-algebras. Consider extensions of $A$ by $B\otimes K$. Put $Q\left(B\right)=M\left(B\otimes K\right)/B\otimes K$, where $K$ is the $C^*$-algebra of all compact operators in the separable Hilbert space. An extension $\tau : A\to Q\left(B\right)$ is called trivial if there exists $\sigma: A\to M\left(B\otimes K\right)$ such that $\tau=\pi\circ \sigma$.
Definition: By identifying $M_{2}\left(Q\left(B\right)\right)$ with $Q\left(B\right)$ via an isometry $v\in M_{2}\left(Q\left(B\right)\right)$ with $v^*v=1_2$ and $vv^*=1$, we may add $\tau_1, \tau_2 :A \to Q\left(B\right)$ by defining $\tau_1\oplus\tau_2$ to be $v\left(\tau_1\oplus\tau_2\right)v^*$.
Let $A$ be a separable $C^*$-algebra and $\tau: A\to Q\left(B\right)$ be an extension, where $Q\left(B\right)=M\left(B\otimes K\right)/B\otimes K$. Why is there a trivial extension $\tau_0:A\to Q\left(B\right)$ such that $\tau\oplus \tau_0$ is essential?
This is an exercise in Chapter Five of the book "An introduction to the Classification of Amenable $C^*$-algebras" written by H. Lin.
I do not even know how to find the extension $\tau_0$.

Would you mind writing down some definitions? Like, what do you mean by $\tau$ being “an extension”? What do you mean by $K$ (I assume that’s the algebra of compact operators)? What do you mean by “a trivial extension”? How is $\tau \oplus \tau_0$ defined (I assume this uses $M_2(K) \simeq K$)? And what do you mean by $\tau \oplus \tau_0$ being “essential”? It’s not good practice to ask people to check the book you refer to in order to understand the question.

@DavidGao Of course. I wrote down the extra definitions. Thank you for your reply.

Have you read my answer to this question yet, or do you still need additional details…?

@DavidGao I have read your answer, but I don't understand the core of your hint. I am not familiar with some definitions depended on representations theory. I will appreciate If you could give me more details. Thank you for your comments.

There is no real representation theory in my answer though. You can just replace the word “representation” by “$\ast$-homomorphism” and the word “faithful” by “injective”. They mean the same thing.

Hint: observe that, for $\tau: A \to M(B)/B$, the induced extension of $A$ by $B$ is essential iff $\tau$ is injective. Now observe that, for any separable $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, if we choose a faithful representation $\pi: A \to B(\ell^2) = M(K(\ell^2))$, then $\pi \otimes 1_{\ell^2}: A \to B(\ell^2 \otimes \ell^2) \simeq B(\ell^2) = M(K(\ell^2))$ is a representation s.t. $\tau’ = q \circ (\pi \otimes 1_{\ell^2})$ is injective, where $q: M(K(\ell^2)) \to M(K(\ell^2))/K(\ell^2)$ is the quotient map.
